# container should follow the aspect ratio of the video child

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a container and a video as a child element:

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}

.child {
  height: 260px;
  display: inline;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <video src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" class="child"></video>
</div>
```

I want to resize the video height and the container width and heght should follow like there is a single element not two !!

How can I do this ?

Note that we want the original aspect ratio of the video even by changing the height of it and the container should follow the changes of video

Comment: inline-flex instead of flex ?

Comment: **the container should follow the changes of video** not the opposite

Answer (score 1):

This works natively.

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.child {
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <video src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" class="child"></video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`width:` [min-content](https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-min-content-max-content-fit-content-css/) on `.container` allows it's width to conform to the width of it's content like shrink wrap.

In the example, the range `<input>` will change the height of the video. The video will keep it's AR naturally. Note that the red border of `.container` always conforms to the video's dimensions.

**JavaScript is only for demonstration purposes**

```js
document.forms[0].oninput = changeVideoHeight;

function changeVideoHeight(e) {
  const fc = this.elements;
  fc.hpx.value = fc.ht.value + "px";
  document.querySelector('.child').style.height = fc.ht.value + "px";
}
```

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: auto;
  width: min-content;
}

.child {
  height: 260px;
  display: inline;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Height:&nbsp;
  <input id='ht' type='range' min='90' max='405' value='260'>
  &nbsp;<output id='hpx'></output></label>
  
  <div class='container'>
    <video src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" class="child"></video>
  </div>
  
</form>
```